# coverage of django application deployed on production server

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, code-coverage, coverage.py

Can anyone please tell how to find the coverage of django application deployed in apache.I want to hook in coverage.py in the deployed django application.

Comment: `coverage.py` !!! can you elaborate more about this .

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to Ned Batchelder's excellent coverage.py.

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/

Why dont you make use of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-coverage?